# Constructor not defined and Type not visible error

Tags: apex, lightning, unit-test, controller, code-coverage

I have a apex class which has a sub class and a constructor.
below is the apex code

```
public static final List<String> alphabetArr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
private class ppa_struct {
        private String ppaId;
        private String loanNum;
        private String attributeName;
        private List<DocGroup> docGroups;

        public ppa_struct(Custom_purchase_group__c ppa, Custom_rule_group prm) {
            ppaId = ppa.Id;
            loanNum = ppa.loan_num__c;
            attributeName = ppa.Attribute_Name__c;
            docGroups = new List<DocGroup>();
            for (Integer i = 0; i < prm.Document_Groups__r.size(); i++) {
                docGroups.add(new DocGroup(prm.Document_Groups__r[i], alphabetArr[i]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, ppa_struct is the sub class and inside is its constructor.
Now, as ppa_struct is private, when i call this class in test class as below,

```
PPAController.ppa_struct struct = new PPAController.ppa_struct ();
```

I am getting the error as

> Type is not visible: PPAController.ppa_struct

Now, when i change the class to public instead of private, i am getting the following error in test class

> Constructor not defined: [PPAController.ppa_struct].()

Can anyone please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, a private class is not accessible outside the top-level class directly. This is data encapsulation, and a desirable behavior.

The second problem is caused because you tried to call a zero-argument constructor, but there is only a two-argument constructor. Like Java and other ancestor languages (e.g. C++), if you do not have a constructor at all, you get a zero-argument constructor automatically, but if you provide *any other* constructor, the zero-argument constructor must be explicitly written in to the class.

That can be as simple as:

```
public ppa_struct() {
}
```

Either provide the required two parameters, or write in a zero-argument constructor to use with the test. If you want the class to be private, but test-accessible, you can write:

```
@TestVisible private class ppa_struct {
  ...
```

Which will allow unit tests to see this class, but not other classes external to the top-level class.